# Word to describes the money that you lend to somebody?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, finance, money

I am confused about using words related to money.

I have looked up in Oxford Learner's dictionaries. The word "loan" has the meaning: [*money that an organization lends and somebody borrows*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/loan_1?q=loan).

On the contrary, which word (or a **phrase**) describes "money that you lend somebody"?

I have a project about finance. It includes a lot of financial English words. I have to describe "the amount of money that you earn", "the amount of money that you pay", "the amount of money that you borrow from somebody" and "the amount of money that you lend to somebody"

**Edited:** Finally, I decided to choose the word *income/expenditure/debt/loan* for my purpose. I am so sorry for my inconsistency. Thank you for all your attention. Thank you!

Comment: I use Oxford dictionary. There are some example sentences:

"It took two years to repay my student loan.";

"I even gave her the loan of my car.";

I mean which word is opposite in meaning to "borrowed money".

Comment: Why don't you **cite/quote those two examples**? I understand your confusion now. If nobody answers in a couple of hours I will but I can't now, I'm too busy.

Comment: Uh, it's still a loan?

Comment: I have a project about finance. It includes a lot of financial English words. I have to describe "the amount of money that you earn", "the amount of money that you pay", "the amount of money that you borrow from sb" and "the amount of money that you lend sb".

Comment: "promissory note" or "bond" are artifacts of a loan that go to the lender when the money goes to the borrower

Comment: 'Personal Finance & Money' site may be best for this multifaceted question

Comment: The four things you have been asked for are :- income/expenditure/borrowings/loans. The last two can be further clarified as 'outstanding debts' and 'outstanding loans'.

Comment: Are you looking for something more lender-specific than *principal*?

Comment: Oh, Lawrence. That's exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much for your help. 

Thank Nigel J for very useful words.

Comment: What's "principal"? How does that fit in with lending an amount of money? @Lawrence

Comment: It's not true a loan only refers to an organisation lending money. A loan is simply an instance of lending. Anyone can lend. You'd be unnecessarily muddying the waters by using "principal" instead of simply "loan". Also, "principal" is a more technical term, and if I lend you my car or $20 we'd never call it a principal. But it's your word.

Comment: https://www.lendingtree.com/glossary/what-is-principal

Comment: @Mari-Lou A An amount of capital originally borrowed or invested, but as I explained in my comment in my opinion they should simply use "loan".

Comment: Oh, so if I use "income/expenditure/borrowings/loans" for my project, does almost everyone understand what I mean?

Comment: [@Mari-LouA](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442641/which-word-in-english-describes-the-money-that-you-lend-somebody?noredirect=1#comment1062868_442641) It's the original amount invested by the lender, not including fees, interest, etc. But it's also the original amount borrowed.

Comment: @Lawrence "Principal" is only used in the context of formal loans which incur interest and charges, though. If I lent my son £20 I don't think I'd call it "principal". I'd probaly call it a "loan" or, if I needed to be a bit more formal, an "advance"

Comment: @BoldBen In an informal setting, I have the impression that verbs are used more: *he lent this, they borrowed that*. ‘Principal’ doesn’t sound particularly formal to me - no more so than ‘advance’. My interest (no pun intended :) ) in introducing the term was to find out whether the OP wanted something (more) lender-specific.

Comment: @Lawrence What I meant by formal loans was ones which attract interest (including those from loan sharks) as opposed to casual loans to friends and family. _Principal_, really, only makes sense as a description of part of the total repayments. Where the loan is casual the amount to be paid back is the same as the amount leant so can't really be described as _the principal_

Comment: @BoldBen Ah, I see what you mean. With an informal loan, I'd expect "Can I please have my *money* back?" more than "Please repay the loan/principal".

Comment: @Lawrence Spot on, me too. "Here's that sick squid I owe you" and all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A customer who wishes to make an important purchase, or has urgent repairs  will *ask for* a **[personal loan](https://www.halifax.co.uk/loans/)**:

And he or she will **apply for** a bank loan

> *[You can apply for up to £50,000](https://www.halifax.co.uk/loans/compare-loans/personal-loan/)*

On the other hand, a bank *provides finance* (or funding); *gives out* or *approves of* loans.

The bank **lends** money to its customers. The customer **borrows** money from the bank after he or she has successfully *applied for a loan*. Therefore the bank is the **lender**, and the customer is the **borrower**

Answer (score 1):

**Debt** is something, **especially money**, that is owed to someone else, or the state of owing something (according to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/debt)):

- He could no longer pay his debts.
- I owe him nearly $10,000 and my debt is growing every day.
- I'm up to my eyeballs in debt.

Perhaps, **loan** is still the word you are looking for because it's possible to say *"She needed money, so she asked her friend for a loan."* *Loan* doesn't necessarily mean money borrowed from a bank.

Comment: Is it a synonym of "loan"?
I want to ask
"The amount of money you borrow from sb" is a loan.
"The amount of money you lend to sb" is ...? (a word or a phrase)

Comment: You don't really say that you gave someone else a debt. You give him a loan.

Comment: How to discriminate the loan "you lend" and the loan "you borrow"? I need a phrase. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The answer is edited. Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much, Enguroo. But how to discriminate between the loan "you lend" and the loan "you borrow"?

Comment: The "kind" of loan should be clear from context. Thank you for the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "to fund - as a verb" or "funds - as a noun", as describing the act of providing or the money provided for loan purposes (purposes not described). There are other words that can be used, for example - "capitalize", capital and  "subsidize", subsidy. The words are commonly used in finance with many applications.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fund

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/funds?s=t

Answer (score 1):

A has money.  B needs money.  A and B can be individuals or banks or other organizations.  Here are some sentences that show you how to use these basic words.  This list is not exhaustive (complete), but it should help with what you would like to do.  (And by the way, next time you have a basic question like this -- ask it on ELL so you don't end up drowning in a lot fine print.)

A lends B money.

A lends money to B.

A makes a loan to B.

A gives B a loan.

A loans B some money.

B borrows money from A.

B earns a good income but he has a lot of expenditures this month.  Therefor he needs to take out a loan.

B will gradually pay off the loan with monthly payments.

A: "B, do you need a loan?"

B: "A, could you lend me some money?"

B: "A, could you loan me some money?"

B goes to the bank to apply for a loan.  When he gets there, he says, "I'd like to apply for a loan."

The loan officer helps B fill out the application.

The next day, the loan officer calls B with the good news that his loan was approved and the funds have been deposited in his account.

Comment: Hao Nguyen, make sure you get to know ELL, it's a great site.  Also check out linguee.com, which gives lots of real-world example sentences.  Also, of all the dictionaries I know, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/loan is the one that shows the most example sentences.  (I personally learn better from example sentences than from dictionaries.)